How to correctly index a dataframe with a function?
Given a dataframe:
   a  b  c
u  5  0  3
v  3  7  9
w  3  5  2

I'd like to select rows/columns in a dataframe using a function. This function gets the dataframe and returns a tuple of lists of labels, e.g. it returns ['v', 'u'], ['c'] using this lambda:
get_labels = lambda df: (['v', 'u'], ['c'])

If I use .loc with the label literals, I get the desired result:
df.loc[['v', 'u'], ['c']]

   c
v  9
u  3

The documentation says about using a function (a callable), that a function returning two lists of labels is valid ("one of the above"):

A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above)

But if I use .loc with the function, which I believe returns the same list tuple, I get an error:
df.loc[get_labels]

unhashable type: 'list'

What's wrong? (as a possible clue: Pandas seems trying to create an Index object with the result of the function -- don't know why, no explanation in the documentation.)

Full code:
import numpy.random as npr
import pandas as pd
npr.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(npr.randint(10, size=(3,3)),
                  index=['u','v','w'],
                  columns=['a','b','c'])

get_labels = lambda df: (['v', 'u'], ['c'])
print(df.loc[['v', 'u'], ['c']])
print(df.loc[get_labels])


@Plagon if you do this, you no longer have a function but a tuple a function and a list

Yea I just realized :D

As noted in the loc documentation, you need to pass:


A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (note that 5 is interpreted as a label of the index, and never as an integer position along the index).
A list or array of labels, e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c'].
A slice object with labels, e.g. 'a':'f'.
A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g. [True, False, True].
An alignable boolean Series. The index of the key will be aligned before masking.
An alignable Index. The Index of the returned selection will be the input.
A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the
above)


Although maybe a bit ambiguous in the documentation, all of these are applicable to one axis.
df.loc['a']                  # single label
df.loc[['a', 'b', 'c']]      # list of labels
df.loc['a':'f']              # slice
df.loc[[True, False, True]]  # list of booleans
df.loc[pd.Series([True], index=['a']) # series
df.loc[pd.Index(['a'])]      # index
df.loc[lambda x: ['a', 'b']] # callable

In your case, the callable returns two indexers, making it as if you were passing them to the index locator:
df.loc[(['v', 'u'], ['c']), :]

You would need one callable per axis:
get_index = lambda x: ['u', 'v']
get_col = lambda x: ['c']
df.loc[get_index, get_col]


You need to call your function:
df.loc[get_labels(df)]

To use in a chain:
df.pipe(lambda x: x.loc[get_labels(x)])

In my opinion, it might be better to have the function perform the selection directly:
def get_labels(df):
    return df.loc[['v', 'u'], ['c']]

df.pipe(get_labels)

Output:
   c
v  9
u  3


No you dont. A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above) docs

@Plagon yes you do, if you pass a callable it will work on one axis, see updata

@mins then use pipe

@mins a callable should return an indexer for one axis (index or columns) as shown in my update. Here you try to pass both thus it uses (['v', 'u'], ['c']) as two indices ['v', 'u'] and ['c'] for the index

In short, you're doing df.loc[(['v', 'u'], ['c']), :]

I came to the same conclusion, and posted a complement.

From mozway's answer, it appears there is a problem in the documentation. I'm providing here some explanations for whoever is confronted with the same questions.
Indexing can be done by using labels or a Boolean mask.
As the documentation is written:

A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above).

... it seems to include the two cases, but I believe this is wrong, it only includes the Boolean mask case, and it should be completed this way:

When using labels, provide two functions, one for rows, one for columns, both returning "one of the above", except Booleans.

When using a Boolean mask, provide a single function returning Booleans.


To make my case work, I've split the function in two:
get_rows = lambda df: ['v', 'u']
get_cols = lambda df: ['c']
print(df.loc[get_rows, get_cols])

However having the two lists coming from separate function is indeed problematic. If rows/columns to select are interdependent, then some common calculation must be called twice, e.g. let's say we want to get the subset of rows/columns having the same label, case insensitive:
   B  J  A  C  H  L
g  3  7  8  5  7  2
f  7  8  0  7  4  8
k  4  4  0  4  8  0
l  0  4  7  3  7  7
b  2  2  1  7  0  7

   B  L
b  2  7
l  0  7

This code works, with the inconvenient common_labels is called twice (in this specific case it could be optimized, this is an example):
import string
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
import pandas as pd


r, c = 5, 6
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:max(r,c)*2]

# Create a df
rnd_labels = lambda n: npr.choice(letters, n, replace=False)
rows = rnd_labels(r)
cols = np.char.upper(rnd_labels(c))
values = npr.randint(10, size=(r,c))
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=rows, columns=cols)

# Common function called twice
common_labels = lambda df: np.intersect1d(
    df.index,
    df.columns.astype('U4').str.lower())

# Functions used in .loc
rows_labels = lambda df: common_labels(df)
cols_labels = lambda df: np.char.upper(common_labels(df).astype('U4'))

# Select rows/columns
sub_df = df.loc[rows_labels, cols_labels]
print(df, sub_df, sep='\n'*2)

